# Prototype: How to know the prototype.js version using a js function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, version, prototypejs

In jQuery you can use `$().jquery;` and you can know your framework version, is there an equal script for prototype?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [Prototype.Version](http://api.prototypejs.org/Prototype/Version/).

Comment: So, which is the js funcion? Example? Thank you